# Grapes in a Microwave - Experiment

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, electromagnetic-radiation

I am considering attempting an experiment in which one puts two, almost severed, halves of a grape in a microwave with a glass over it. To my knowledge so far, the grape halves act as focal point for the radiation and the microwaves will burn the small part of grape skin that isn't severed, providing a spark which the microwaves will stimulate into plasma, contained by the glass jar. Three questions: is the experiment reasonably safe, am I correct in my understanding of the experiment, and what compounds will the plasma form once it cools?

Comment: Sadly, [it's not a plasma just a flame](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37836/why-do-grapes-in-a-microwave-oven-produce-plasma). It's good fun and quite safe. I hear claims that it can damage your microwave oven, but mine has suffered no damage from repeated experiments with grapes. You don't need the jar.